# How do I forget my credentials for git from the command line?

Tags: repository, git, authentication, atom

I am trying to forget my credentials for git so I can close a repository using a PAT.

```
~# git clone git@github.com:your-username/atom.git
Cloning into 'atom'...
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '140.82.113.4' to the list of known hosts.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
~#
```

It does not ask for my password so that I can enter the PAT. I have tried searching this up, but most of the information found to help is for MacOS, and I am using Ubuntu. I have tried the following commands with no luck:

```
~# git config --system --unset credential.helper
~# git config --system --unset credential.helper
~# git config --local --unset credential.helper
fatal: --local can only be used inside a git repository
```

Please assist me with learning how to clear my credentials so that I may use this PAT to clone this git repository. Thank you.

Comment: Why are you running as root?

Comment: [Running as root can cause this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15696244). Also, you shouldn't be running as root in the first place, that's what `sudo` is for. If this is because you don't like to repeatedly type in your password, `sudo` usually only asks for your password the first time, although, it will reset after a certain period of time of like 5 minutes.

Comment: But this is why I was asking why you are running as root. It is recommended to sometimes run as root but only when you have a good reason to do so. [Git won't work from root if you originally created the credentials under a non-root user](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/error-permission-denied-publickey). Instructions appear to be the same for linux and mac but you can click on the "linux" tab on the article to view the linux instructions.